# Interpolate hair curve leaves only one strand

Tags: geometry-nodes, hair

I have tried using the Blender hair system a couple of different ways. I am new to blender in general and I am trying to learn to make mods.

I have tried using geometry nodes and the built-in hair assets however, no matter what I do when I add the interpolate hair curves I am left with only one hair on the head. Any ideas why this could be?

Edit: added picture of the before a add interpolate

[image: After Interpolate is added]
[image: before interpolate is added]

Comment: is there any guide curves yet?

Comment: Yes there are. I added a picture to show before using interpolate.

Answer (score 0):

The *Interpolate Hair Curves* node needs a Surface to interpolate the curves. You can either add the scalp object to the orange "Surface:" socket or use an [Object Info Node](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/geometry_nodes/input/scene/object_info.html) to add the scalp's geometry to the light green "Surface" socket.

[image]